# Why is Bootstrap's CSS overwriting my CSS?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, react-bootstrap

In my HTML document, I list the Bootstrap CSS FIRST, then my CSS files follow. Yet, some of my rules are being ignored and in the Developer Tools I can see that Bootstrap's CSS is slashing through my CSS putting their rules at the top of the DevTools window. My HTML's head looks like this...

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./images/favicon.ico" />
<title>Fictional Shop</title>
<!--Bootstrap CSS-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!--Fonts-->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merienda" rel="stylesheet">
<!--My CSS-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles/header.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles/footer.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles/homePage.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles/aboutPage.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles/productDetails.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles/main.css" />
```

Any clue why Bootstrap would ever be overpowering my CSS when I declare it first, before my custom CSS files?

Comment: You need to tell us much more than this. Which exact styles? Provide an actual example.

Comment: There are some CSS rules that browsers follow (the more exact rule is provided (ID > class), the higher priority it has).

Comment: Without details, I'm going to speculate that your rules may be falling victim to the [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) rules.

Comment: Don't forget CSS specificity as well as precedence

Comment: It's going to be a specificity issue, the cascade (order of CSS files/selectors) is only one aspect of how which properties and styles will be applied. If Bootstrap has `#one .two` defined and you define `.two`, any properties defined by `#one .two` will override the properties defined by `.two` in your CSS. The specificity of `#one .two` is `0 1 1 0` and `.two` is `0 0 1 0`. The priority of these numbers is left to right. The second number is `0` for `.two` but `1` for `#one .two`. Your style is less specific and will not get applied. Also, consider combining all your CSS files into one file.

Comment: Side note, but you should combine all those css files into one. There is no need to make it harder on your browser

Comment: @hungerstar thank you for explaining that. the instances where this occurs is usually on Bootstrap components that I am trying to overwrite certain things for. the CSS specificity rule is probably exactly why I have been having trouble. if you want to list it as an answer, I'll gladly accept it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's going to be a specificity issue, the cascade (order of CSS files/selectors) is only one aspect of how which properties and styles will be applied. If Bootstrap has `#one .two` defined and you define `.two`, any properties defined by `#one .two` will override the properties defined by `.two` in your CSS. The specificity of `#one .two` is `0 1 1 0` and `.two` is `0 0 1 0`. The priority of these numbers is left to right. The second number is `0` for `.two` but `1` for `#one .two`. Your style is less specific and will not get applied.

If you run into a property in a Bootstrap selector that uses `!important` you will also have to use `!important` for that property. Otherwise increase specificity other ways and avoid `!important` if you can.

Also, consider combining all your CSS files into one file.

Answer (score 0):

Use `!important` in your styles which overwrite Bootstrap. The Bootstrap style may have `!important` in the style which overwrites your style even though your style loads after the Bootstrap CSS. `!important` styles applies to your HTML if you not have use `!important` in your styles (when Bootstrap does).

Comment: Using `!important` all over the place is poor design and should only be used when absolutely necessary,

Comment: agreed..! this should do only for the styles that overwrite by bootstrap styles.

Comment: Just commenting to make clear that one should only use `!important` to overwrite properties in a Bootstrap selector that **already have** `!important`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `!important` in those styles/CSS which is overwriting, but this is a temporary solution and its not good practice . Change the order of files like move bootstrap link from top to bottom in header. Hope this works!